# How to split a string with a '\n' delimiter (functions allowed : malloc, free)

Tags: c

I've been taking this intense training session in C for one month now and now I have to code a program that can read from STDIN and recognise some patterns. In order to achieve this, I need to analyse the input line by line.

I've started to code this function but it keeps segfaulting on me ...

```
char    **ft_split_trail(char *str, int *li)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int lines;
    char *line;
char **ret;

lines = ft_count_lines(str);
line = NULL;
*li = lines;
ret = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (lines + 1));
    i = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        j = 0;
        while (str[j + i] != '\n' && str[j + i] != '\0')
        {
            ft_putstr("ok\n");
            line[j] = str[j + i];
            j++;
        }
        ret[i] = malloc(j + 1);
        ret[i] = line;
        ret[i][j] = '\0';
        i += j;
    }
    return (ret);
}
```

I've been tryind to debug my program for 2 hours now, but ca't seem to find any clue...

Comment: for human readability: 1) consistently indent the code.  Suggest 4 spaces after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'.  do not use tabs as each editor/wordprocessor has different tab stops/tab width  2) insert a blank line between code blocks

Comment: strongly suggest using a debugger, like 'gdb' after compiling/linking with all debug info in the resulting file. (for gcc, use -ggdb parameter)

Comment: Always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc() to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 2):

this line:

```
line[j] = str[j + i];
```

is placing character(s) at some offset where 'line' points, but 'line' has not been set to point to anywhere (like some malloc'd memory).  This results in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

this line:

```
ret[i] = line;
```

is copying a pointer.  What is needed is to copy the text of the line.  Suggest:

```
strncpy( ret[i], line, j );
```

Comment: Thank's, I'll have to recode a strncpy of my own because I'm not allowed to use functions that I didn't code myself except malloc and free

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ft_count_lines(const char *str){
    int i, count = 0;

    for(i = 0; str[i]; ++i){
        if(str[i] == '\n')
            ++count;
    }
    if(i && str[i-1] != '\n')//not only count newline(count line of no newline)
        ++count;

    return count;
}

//count character upto newline or NUL
int ft_count_upto_lineEnd(const char *str){
    int i, count = 0;

    for(i = 0; str[i] && str[i] != '\n'; ++i)
        ++count;

    return count;
}

char **ft_split_trail(const char *str, int *li){
    int i, j, len, lines, line;
    char **ret;

    *li = lines = ft_count_lines(str);
    ret = malloc(sizeof(char*) * lines);//no need to +1

    for(line = i = 0; str[i];){
        len = ft_count_upto_lineEnd(&str[i]);
        ret[line] = malloc(len + 1);
        for(j = 0; j < len; ++j, ++i)
            ret[line][j] = str[i];//copy
        ret[line++][j] = '\0';
        if(str[i] == '\n')
            ++i;//skip newline
    }

    return ret;
}
//DEMO
int main(void){
    char *data =
        "What are little boys made of, made of?\n"
        "What are little boys made of?\n"
        "Frogs and snails And puppy-dog's tails,\n"
        "That's what little boys are made of.\n"
        "\n"
        "What are little girls made of,made of?\n"
        "What are little girls made of?\n"
        "Sugar and spice And all things nice,\n"
        "That's what little girls are made of.\n"
        "\n"
        "What are young men made of, made of?\n"
        "What are young men made of?\n"
        "Sighs and leers And crocodile tears,\n"
        "That's what young men are made of.\n"
        "\n"
        "What are young women made of,made of?\n"
        "What are young women made of?\n"
        "Ribbons and laces And sweet pretty faces,\n"
        "That's what young men are made of.";//"That's what young men are made of.\n" same result
    int i, line;
    char **lines = ft_split_trail(data, &line);

    for(i = 0; i < line; ++i){
        puts(lines[i]);
        free(lines[i]);
    }
    free(lines);

    return 0;
}
```